# beginner programming student with parallel arrays

Tags: c++

Beginner programmer with huge amount of respect for all programmers. My hair is gone and there are times I feel drained from trying to solve these problems. Anyhoot current assignment has me read in data from .txt file which I've done. Perform a calculation and output to screen. The read in data has more variables than what I'm supposed to write to an output file. So I've read in data and now I have to read in tripNumber and FinalCost into two different arrays then write the data in Reverse to a file. I've got most of it but am stuck in a couple spots which should be clear in my code. Realize everyone has their own issues and this isn't a sad story. I work 60+ hours a week and am trying to get a degree. Thanks for any help or advice in making this complex skill easier to comprehend.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;
int main()
{

//create two arrays
const int ARRAY_SIZE = 100; //array size of 100 elements

ifstream fileIn; //create file object 
ofstream fileSave; //create new output file
fileIn.open("TripInput.txt"); //read in file

//Variables to hold data from the file
int tripNbr = 0;
double fuelCost = 0;
double fuelTotal = 0;
double wasteDisp = 0;
double misCost = 0;

int counter = 0;

int nbrOfTrip[ARRAY_SIZE];
double totalCost[ARRAY_SIZE];

for(counter = 0; counter < ARRAY_SIZE; counter++)
{
nbrOfTrip[counter] = 0;
totalCost[counter] = 0;
}

cout<<"Welcome to My Space Travel Company"<<endl;
cout<<endl;
cout<<"Trip No"<<setw(10)<<"Fuel"<<setw(10)<<"Waste"<<setw(10)<<"Misc"<<setw(15)
<<"Discount Fuel"<<setw(15)<<"Final Cost"<<endl;

if(fileIn.fail())//test to see if file opened
{
cout<<"File did not open."<<endl;
}

while(fileIn>>tripNbr>>fuelCost>>wasteDisp>>misCost) //while loop to read in data from   file
{
fuelTotal = fuelCost - (fuelCost * .10);
double finalCost = fuelTotal + wasteDisp + misCost;
cout<<tripNbr<<setprecision(2)<<fixed<<setw(14)<<fuelCost<<setw(10)<<wasteDisp
    <<setw(10)<<misCost<<setw(15)<<fuelTotal<<setw(15)<<finalCost<<endl;

//Write trip number and final cost to the 2 parallel arrays...not sure how to
//to do this.


//open output file
fileSave.open("TripCost.txt");

//for loops to output data to file
for(counter = 0; counter < ARRAY_SIZE; counter++)
{
fileSave<< nbrOfTrip[counter]<<endl;
fileSave<< totalCost[counter]<<endl;
}
}
system("Pause");
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Couple of things occur to me. First your 'while loop to read in data from file' ends at the wrong place. It should be

```
while(fileIn>>tripNbr>>fuelCost>>wasteDisp>>misCost) //while loop to read in data from   file
{
    fuelTotal = fuelCost - (fuelCost * .10);
    double finalCost = fuelTotal + wasteDisp + misCost;
    cout<<tripNbr<<setprecision(2)<<fixed<<setw(14)<<fuelCost<<setw(10)<<wasteDisp
        <<setw(10)<<misCost<<setw(15)<<fuelTotal<<setw(15)<<finalCost<<endl;

    //Write trip number and final cost to the 2 parallel arrays...not sure how to
    //to do this.

}
```

You have this loop ending after you output to the file. Which means you'll output the file multiple times, which isn't right.

Secondly, writing the trip number and final cost to the array is very straightforward. You just need an extra variable to keep count of how many trips you've added. I've called this 'numberOfTrips'. Like this

```
int numberOfTrips = 0;
while(fileIn>>tripNbr>>fuelCost>>wasteDisp>>misCost) //while loop to read in data from   file
{
    fuelTotal = fuelCost - (fuelCost * .10);
    double finalCost = fuelTotal + wasteDisp + misCost;
    cout<<tripNbr<<setprecision(2)<<fixed<<setw(14)<<fuelCost<<setw(10)<<wasteDisp
        <<setw(10)<<misCost<<setw(15)<<fuelTotal<<setw(15)<<finalCost<<endl;

    //Write trip number and final cost to the 2 parallel arrays
    nbrOfTrip[numberOfTrips] = tripNbr;
    totalCost[numberOfTrips] = finalCost;
    ++numberOfTrips;
}
```

Finally when you write the data to the file, you should only write the number of entries added to the parallel arrays, not the whole arrays. So the final loop should use the 'numberOfTrips' variable from the previous loop. Like this

```
//for loops to output data to file
for(counter = 0; counter < numberOfTrips; counter++)
{
    fileSave<< nbrOfTrip[counter]<<endl;
    fileSave<< totalCost[counter]<<endl;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. Could you help me understand the use of the arrays you have shown? I'm not quite understanding the parameter inside the array. Also, the numberOfTrips is incremented, would it make a difference if it were written like this numberOfTrips++ ? Lastly, when I am writing to the file is there a way to write the contents of the array in reverse? Ideally, it would help me if i understood how it works in reverse. Again much thanks!

Comment: The code above is using `numberOfTrips` to count how many items have been added to the arrays. Of course the arrays have a certain fixed size (which is `ARRAY_SIZE`). But in this code we don't want to use all the entries in the array, which just want to use the number of entries in the input file. So we need the extra variable to count how many items we are using in the arrays. That variable starts at zero and gets incremented each time a trip is added to the arrays. This way the variable also holds the position in the array to add the next item.

Comment: `numberOfTrips++` or `++numberOfTrips` makes no difference in this situation. Choose which ever one you prefer.

Comment: To reverse the output of the data just change the final loop, instead of starting a 0 and gonig up to numberOfTrips - 1, start at numberOfTrips - 1 and go down to 0.

Comment: John, I sincerely appreciate the assistance and time you took to answer and actually teach. I have a much better understanding of how the arrays work and the manipulation of the output to the file. There are several other programming classes that await me. I'm thankful there is help via the keyboard and web. Hopefully as I learn more maybe I will be of assistance to someone else, although that is years down the road.